# Java LinkedList iterator being exhausted prematurely

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I am using `LinkedList` and retrieving an `Iterator` object by using `list.iterator()`. After that, I am checking `it.hasNext()`, real issue is while checking `it.hasNext()`, sometimes it returns `false`. I need help why this is happening, though I have elements in the list.

Some code:

```
public synchronized void check(Object obj) throws Exception {
    Iterator itr = list.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()) { //This Line I get false.. though i have list size is 1

        Item p = (Item)itr.next();
        if(p.getId() == null) {continue;}
        if(p.getId().getElemntId() == obj.getId() || obj.getId() == 0 ) {
            p.setResponse(obj);
            notifyAll();
            return;
        }
    }
    Log.Error("validate failed obj.getId="+obj.getId()+" **list.size="+list.size()*This shows 1*);
    throw new Exception("InvalidData");
}
```

Comment: If it.hasNext() == false, it means that your list is empty. For a more complete answer, we need to see some code ...

Comment: @Sujeet try debugging by printing list.size() -- it's unlikely that iterator will return false even if there is elements in list (given it is coded correctly)

Comment: It is a multi threaded application ..can not share the full code :(. I need help like have u encountered this kind of Issue..is there any scenario where it.hasNext() returns false though the list is not empty.

Comment: Are you iterating over `it` more than once? `Iterator` s are only good for one iteration and then you must call `list.iterator()` to get a new `Iterator`.

Comment: You say it's a multi-threaded application. Are multiple threads accessing this `LinkedList` and/or this `Iterator`?

Comment: Iterator it=list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
it.next()
// do things
}

S.O.P("List size()"+list.size());

Comment: @Sujeet: Perhaps you should edit your question to include the code instead of using the comments.

Comment: I know how to check this kind of issue in my application, as list is shared Object so wait() & notify will solve. but my concern is why i am getting this issue, do not have solid answer why i am getting false though i have elements in list.

Comment: @Sujeet: `wait()` and `notify()` do not automatically solve the multi-threading problem. We cannot solve your problem without seeing the actual code. Perhaps you could edit your question to include **only** the code that deals with the list.

Answer (score 4):

...well, hasNext() returns false once you reached the end of the list.
Please post your code to see what's wrong. Either you don't have the expected elements in your list or you are calling next() more often than you expect.

Edit:
Indeed, since it's multithreaded, Nishant said it right, check that your list is thread safe by using:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList(...));
```

Edit 2:

Perhaps two threads are accessing the list concurrently. If the error sometimes happen, sometimes not, this may be the case.

If you have such a piece of code running in several threads:

```
if (it.hasNext())
  T elem = it.next()
  process(elem)
```

It may be that:
Thread 1 and 2 say "ok, there is a next element", then switch context, then both become running again at some time and both want to retrieve an element though there is only one available.

To solve this, make your method 'synchronized'

```
  synchronized void processItem(Iterator<T> it)
  {
    if (it.hasNext())
      T elem = it.next()
      process(elem)
  }
```

Comment: @Sujeet: If your list contains 7 items, then you can call `it.next()` 7 times before `it.hasNext()` returns `false`. At that point, you have reached the end of the list.

Comment: As I am restricting my cache to 1 element only.

Comment: Are you actually iterating over the list in a loop? `Iterator.hasNext()` will *of course* return false when the iterator has reached the end of the list. Note that simply changing the List to a synchronised list will not make it safe, you will still get `ConcurrentModificationException`. A safer bet is `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, assuming that reads are more common than writes.

Comment: only if one tries to actually add something to the list while iterating over it at the same time

Comment: public synchronized void check(Object obj)
   throws Exception {
   
   Iterator itr = list.iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Item p = (Item)itr.next();
    if(p.getId() == null) {continue;}

    if(p.getId().getElemntId() == obj.getId() ||
       obj.getId() == 0
       ) {
     p.setResponse(obj);
     notifyAll();
     return;
    }
   }
   
            Log.Error("validate failed obj.getId="+obj.getId()+" list.size="+list.size());
            throw new Exception("InvalidData");
  }

Comment: Above is the code snippet.. so when ever i get false it throws Exception but same time I can see size 1.

Comment: So my question is, can we have scenarios where iterator fails validation

Comment: @Sujeet: please update your question with the code snippet that you pasted in the comment above.

Comment: Please find the specified lines

Comment: HI All, after so much debug able to find root cause :) Thanks all for your time

Answer (score 3):

See this, it's not thread safe. If you are using multithreaded code please make sure it is synchronized. [See here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

"Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:"

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

After so much debug able to find the root cause and is due to time out between sockets, it was being removed from List,

Thanks
Sujeet